# How can i create a Floating Button Using jQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, .net, css

```
var name = "#floatMenu";
var menuYloc = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0, $(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var offset = menuYloc + $(document).scrollTop() + "px";
        $(name).animate({ top: offset }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
    });
```

How can i create a floating button using jQuery and CSS?

Comment: You mean like `float:left;` or `float:right;` or like a modal window with a button? Or maybe `float` in the sense that it is OVERTOP of something?

Comment: https://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/018_Floating_Menu/demo/dhtml_float_menu_final_nettut.html . chek this link . they are floating menu . i want to add floating to a button in aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could achieve a floating button much simpler with css `position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 100px`. This would always be visible when you scroll the page and on the same spot.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options you can choose from.

CSS or JavaScript (like you attempt in your snippet)

Chris Coyier has explained this already, so I'm just going to link to his page: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

Using the CSS method, you won't get any juicy animations.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to create a floating button/link will be the following.

```
<a href="#" style="position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;"> Preview </a>
```